# Angular ng-repeat renders template before iterator is populated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my ng page loads containing the ng-repeat markup below, it renders the IMG tag before the iterator is populated, but because no src value is present, that generates a 404 for the partial src.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in preview_data.items">
        <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{item.id}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{item.thumb}}" /></a>
    </div>
```

Then my controller kicks in and populates it with the right list of videos.

How do I stop the HTML from getting rendered until the controller is ready with the data?

The page is called by this route:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    console.log('config');
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/createFeed.html",
        controller: "CreateFeedController"
    });
});
```

which calls a factory to get a list of videos to preview from the backend api:

```
app.controller("CreateFeedController", function ($scope, $route, $sce, Preview) {
    var keywords = decodeURIComponent($route.current.params.keywords);
    $scope.preview_data = {
        keywords: keywords
    }
    //pass parameters to web preview API
    Preview.get(keywords, function (data) {

        $scope.preview_data.items = data;

    });


});
app.factory('Preview', function ($http) {
    return{
        get: function (keywords, next) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/preview/', json:true,
                    params: {keywords: keywords}}
            ).success(function (data) {
                    // prepare data here
                    //console.log(data);
                    next(data);
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Check out [this question on SO][1]. You can use either ngClock OR use ng-bind.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871185/angularjs-not-loading-on-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `ng-src` directive instead of the plain `src` attribute in your `img` tag.

From the Angular API for [`ng-src`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc):

> The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: This worked, but I feel bad accepting the answer :) as @Maxim Shoustin had the architecturally sounder advice.

Comment: This is the right answer for your case. Even the ng-cloak won't solve the 404 error, while this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Check the ng-cloak directive.It's intended exactly for this.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Comment: For some reason ng-cloak has no effect in this case. But thank you, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

As you know `$http` returns promise. Therefore your factory is async.

So factory should be like:

```
app.factory('Preview', function ($http, $q) { 

    return{
        get: function (keywords, next) { 

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/preview/', json:true,
                    params: {keywords: keywords}}
            ).success(function (data) {
                      deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function() {
                deferred.reject("Error ...");
            });
            //Returning the promise object
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

And controller:

```
        Preview.get(keywords)   // returns promise
           .then(function (result) {
              $scope.preview_data.items = result;                           
             }, function (result) {
               alert("Error: No data returned");
              });
```

Comment: Thank you for this masterful advice.

Comment: you welcome :) Anyways I think ` ng-src` is better solution in your case. Mine is more generic