# Angularjs not loading on chrome

Tags: angularjs

Some of our app users report seeing handlebar curly braces when they go to the page.
This has been reported by people on chrome (versions vary from 26 to 31). It is happening to a few of the users.
Is there any known issues? The users just send a screenshot with the visible handlebar braces. The app is using Angular JS version 1.0.5

Comment: @DROPtableusers No. It seems JS was not disabled.

Comment: Are you using a CDN for the Angular files? Are you using an alternative (not 80) port number for your website? Does the page fail completely, or is it a 'flash' of handlebars content?

Comment: @robertklep : No we are not using any cdn. It is loaded locally from file. No alternative port, we use 80. The Angular part fails completely and flashes handlebars.

Comment: Care to post the link?

Answer (score 1):

This might be the slow loading of page and Angular displaying the template in raw state as it hasn't compiled the template yet.

As per the [official documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind), you have two options to avoid this -

1. Instead of using `{{model element}}`, you can use `ng-bind = "model element"`.
2. [Use](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) `ngClock` directive which will prevent the raw data from displaying.

Comment: Can be a case. But slow connection is not possible. The error is faced by people on broadband as well.